# Что лучше UPDATE или DELETE+INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

Заметил в одном CMS такую вещь. При необходимости обновлении каких либо записей они делают сначала DELETE потом INSERT новой измененной записи, вместо UPDATE. Это разве лучше? На сколько хороша эта практика и зачем? Например я замечал там даже такое: поля пользователей это отдельные записи в таблице (пол, дата рождения и тд) И если пользователь поменял пол, то удаляются все поля, а потом INSERTтся по новой вместе с обновленным полом. CMS комерческая, вроде адекватный код, в отличие от многих, но вот это мне покоя не даёт

Comment: Коммерческая - не значит хорошая. Можно какую угодно хрень продавать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь идёт о представлении полей отдельными строками, то предположу, что набор полей динамический. Например, пользователь может сам добавлять или удалять поля о себе.

Теперь он что-то поудалял и сохраняет. Как сделать update? Если мы хотим полностью снести удалённые строки, а не записывать в них null (например, чтобы потом искать, у каких пользователей есть такие свойства, или нам просто надо отличать пустую строку от null), то мы должны удалённые строки удалить, изменённые строки обновить, а остальные - не трогать. Это сложно. Гораздо проще всё снести и записать заново.

Да, это довольно распространённая практика при редактировании отношений многие-ко-многим. Не знаю, работает ли это быстрее, но так получается гораздо более простой код.

Comment: если мы говорим о динамическом наборе полей в реляционной БД - как это в принципе выглядит? `<fields>: {"field_a":"value_a"}, {"field_b":"value_b"}` где в `<>` - название колонки, а json'ы через запятую - значения?
Но это же боль в чистом виде, искать по такому сложно и тупо? 
Куда лучше уже использовать какое-то NoSQL решение типа Mongo. 

> то мы должны удалённые строки удалить, изменённые строки обновить, а остальные - не трогать

Здесь не совсем понятно, почему это сложно. Не могли бы Вы более детально описать о чем идет речь?

Comment: ну получается табличка user_fields там user_id, field_id, value. Набором полей пользователь не может оперировать, у него всегда чёткий заданный в админке набор полей. Да, так конечно проще всё нафиг снести и забить по новой. Но я сейчас делаю API к этой CMS. Пытаюсь использовать функции ядра, и такая реализация меня пугает, вот и думаю, стоит ли мне сделать это по своему через update?

Comment: @Ep1demic, зачем json-то? Как @iproger написал.`

Answer (score 1):

Более или менее точно ответить можно только при наличии конкретных примеров запросов.
А вообще это плохая практика(притом я о такой практике слышу впервые), за исключением каких-то специфических случаев сделать `UPDATE` куда эффективнее `DELETE + INSERT`

Comment: Обрати внимание на _"Например я замечал там даже такое: поля пользователей это отдельные записи в таблице (пол, дата рождения и тд)",_ т. е. удаляется не одна запись, а куча строк по признаку.